# Python: Finding string in unknown output type

Tags: python, string, decode

I have been trying to resolve this for a few weeks now...I have a report that is generated from an outside program.

It generates an error log (70K lines long) that can be read as text that looks like this:

[Report Output as Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI3IG.png)

However, when I try to find the string "warnings" in it (confirmed it's there), it doesn't find anything.

I tried looping through it and having Python print out each word it reads and the output looks very strange...as if there is a lot of spacing between each letter:

[Python print out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG5p3.png)

I simply can't figure out why Python reads it like this or how to find the word I'm looking for in the string.

Code I used to loop through the file and print each line:

```
import io

f = open('J:\Temp\Errors\PerfupD.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
for words in lines:
    print(words)
```

Code I use to search:

```
import io

f = open('J:\Temp\Errors\PerfupD.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
if "warnings" in lines:
    print("Error found")
```

I have tried reading it as bytes and searching for b"warnings".
Have tried reading as bytes, decoding to cp437, latin-1, windows-1252 (since decode UTF-8 doesn't work), and then searching...nothing works!!

Please help.

Comment: To be clear, you've done `open('J:\Temp\Errors\PerfupD.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')`?

Comment: From your screenshots it seems like there is space between the letters. Is that the case?

Comment: Does the source file include the extra spaces?

Comment: Actually, I'd try UTF-16.

Comment: @ Tiger: passing the utf-8 argument into open doesn't work (for me) I get an error . @ Rafael: The text file has no space, but the python print out does...not sure why. I accidentally posted the python printout for both images. Fixed. @TemporalWolf: source file has no spaces.

Comment: "an error" What error.

Comment: @ Tiger: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\parser2.py", line 9, in <module>
    f = open('J:\Temp\Errors\PerfupD.txt', 'r', 'utf-8')
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: The code seems to be OK. overall, its almost how I would write it.

Assuming this will narrow the problem to the log. Where is it getting that extra char. Encoding problem?

Are you able to upload the original file?

Comment: I take that back. It would be great if you could give me the original data for testing, but I might have an answer to you

Comment: Tigerhawk...you got it. it was so simple...passing 'utf-8' (or anything else) doesn't work without the "encoding=" behind it. I never noticed that it HAD to have encoding= written in. Thank you!!!!!

Comment: Thanks David, it's resolved.

Comment: ok great. But are you sure? do you have lines that only contain 'warnings'?

Comment: Yes I tested it and it's working fine, thanks again!

Comment: No problem, just want to give you a heads up that you will miss 'warnings' located in strings containing more then the word 'warnings'

Comment: @Javathon Because in Python 3, [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)'s third positional argument is `buffering`, which takes an `int`.